# Is it normal for uPVC window shutters to be pre-fitted to the frame at the factory or not?

Tags: windows, installation, fitting

I recently had some uPVC windows installed at home in South Bombay (Mumbai),
India. It was not a positive experience. The people who manufactured
and installed it were Deceuninck fabricators based in New Bombay (New
Mumbai).

I don't want this to become excessively long, so I won't go into
detail about my buying experience. However, I do have a specific
question about the installation process, so I will describe that in
some detail.

The uPVC window frames and shutters were manufactured at the
factory. Then were then bought to the site where they were installed.
This installation was not exactly a smooth process. There were three
people working on installing 4 windows for basically all of Sunday 9th
November, and then again on Monday from 5.30 pm to 8 pm. That's a lot
of time.

To start with, the installers spent a long time fiddling with the
window frames. They said the frames were supposed to be manufactured
with a total of 5 mm space on the sides, but apparently this had not
been done, at least not consistently, They did a lot of hammering and
filing, particularly on one specific window (call this Window 2).

After that, they spent even more time installing the window shutters
into the windows. There was lots of manipulation and
adjustment. Again, at the end of the installation, they spent several
hours on one shutter (call this Window 4). When working on it on
Sunday, they left the shutter badly misaligned, with a lot of space
showing at the top. When they came back Monday afternoon (5.30 pm or
so), they spent some more time on it. When they were finishing, the
light had gone, and we thought the problem (gap at the top of the
shutter) had been fixed, but it hadn't. At this time
of writing (November 24th) the problem has not yet been fixed.

There were also some minor issues with the top and bottom latches on
the left hand shutter. They were too tight; you had to pull the
windows inward hard to latch them.

In another case, a window (again Window 4) did not close properly,
because there was some obstruction.

In all these cases we had to stand there and point out these issues;
the workers didn't seem to notice them.

I'm puzzled by the extremely manual approach
to setup that is being used here. It seems obvious that a sensible
approach to window installation is to fit the (factory manufactured) uPVC window shutters into the (factory manufactured) uPVC window frames at the factory, making sure they are a perfect fit, before bringing them to the site. The positioning of the shutters with respect to the frame is the only thing that matters, assuming that the frame is correctly installed in a proper vertically oriented position.

Presumably, in a factory there would be machinery/equipment to assist
one in doing so. Doing this only on site seems like a very bad idea,
really labor-intensive, and likely to lead to sub-optimal results as
described above. Is this common practice in this industry, speaking
internationally? I would expect better from a big international
company like Deceuninck. I imagine in countries where labor is more
expensive, this would need to be done differently. Does anyone have
any idea what the prevailing practice in India is?

To be clear, I don't actually *know* that the fabricators didn't fit
the shutters into the window frames at the factory, but comments that
their manager made suggested not. I asked him why they didn't pre-fit
the windows, and he responded that "no-one does that". And if they had
been pre-fitted at the factory, surely it would not have been so much
trouble to install them at the site.

EDIT: It seems that my reasons for asking this question was unclear. I'm not
trying to take any action against the people who did this work. I just want some information about standard industry practices, since (as I have attempted to explain) I found the process used rather puzzling. Or, putting it another way, I want to know whether I should expect similar things from someone else doing similar work. From what people have said so far, what I have experienced is not unusual, which I find surprising. But I'm not familar with the building industry in India, or anywhere else, for that matter.

Comment: This sounds a lot more like a rant than a specific question.

Comment: @Steven Rant? Please give examples of ranting. I disagree. It is quite a specific question, as summarized by the title. If people prefer that I shorten the details of installation problems, I can do so, but I thought it might be useful to give more details/context than less.

Comment: Does this area have building codes and standardized building practices and was this house built using standardized building practices? Sounds like a retrofit into non-standard construction where proper rough-in opening dimensions weren't available and those always involve a lot of extra makework, tinkering and adjustment. A manufactured window expects a rough-in opening of a specific size and generally drops into place with minor adjustment to make sure it's squared up and then fastened into the opening.

Comment: @FiascoLabs: My main question was really about the shutter pre-fitting, since that had the most problems. I cannot imagine how the window opening would be an issue there, since, as I said in the question, the shutter fitting would be relative to the frame. The fabricators did take measurements of the window aperture and custom made the window frames to size. Given that, I don't understand why major adjustment was necessary. Granted, the window opening was probably not perfectly level, particularly in the vertical direction, but with suitable spacing, that should not have been a problem.

Comment: @FiascoLabs To answer your question, the building in question is over 100 years old, so building codes don't really apply. Though in any case, this is India, land of chaos and confusion, where things like building codes are only honored on paper. Also, the pre-existing window space was adjusted in vertical height from around 8 feet to around 5 feet. Also, a granite frame was added for the window to mount on. So, the window opening was probably slightly irregular, but that should not have caused problems with shutter fittings, at least.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to accomplish with this question? Are you dissatisfied with the results? Trying to gather evidence to support trying to make them re-do it? etc.

Comment: @iLikeDirt Yes, to the former, but they claim they will fix the outstanding problem. No to the latter. What good would "gathering evidence" do? Only a lunatic would waste time in consumer court in India. My main purpose is to try to determine for future reference whether incorrect methodology has been used. Or, to put it another way, did they screw up, or was the way they were doing necessary given the prevailing conditions? I hope that serves to clarify; if not, feel free to comment.

Comment: The kind of site fitting you describe is common in all aspects of the building trades. These things aren't like lego blocks; they usually need to be hand-fitted. It sounds like you are unhappy with the workmanship of the people who did the job. if they say they're going to fix it, then good.

Comment: @iLikeDirt: Ok, thank you for commenting. Consider posting an answer if you want. I'm unclear where my logic about pre-fitting the shutters into the panes is missing, though. Why can't the fitting be done in advance, and would it not then make things easier at the site?

Comment: That's a question for the company you bought the shutters from or the crew that did the work, not us.

Comment: @iLikeDirt I've already addressed it to both of them, but have not received a reply, and may not get one. I was asking about standard practices in the industry.

Answer (score 2):

Since most of the world's windows are not prefitted with uPVC shutters, prefitting windows with uPVC shutters at the factory is indeed uncommon.

On the other hand, expending considerable energy to get something installed satisfactorily is rather common in the world of construction.

Comment: To be clear, I'm talking about pre-fitting the (factory manufactured) UPVC window frame with (factory manufactured) uPVC shutters. Both of these were manufactured at the factory. I don't understand what you mean by "Since most of the world's windows are not prefitted with uPVC shutters...".